# Call jQuery function from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

how can i call JQuery from plain Javascript ?

the file.js i have:

```
function setLanguageScript(lang) { 
messages = new Array();
if (typeof(lang) != 'undefined' && lang != null) {
    sessvars.lang = lang;
}
//setting default lang
if (typeof(sessvars.lang) == 'undefined' || sessvars.lang == null) {
    sessvars.lang = 'ro';
}

loadResources(sessvars.lang);
} 


function loadResources(language) {
jQuery().ajax({
type: "GET",
url: language + ".xml",
dataType: "xml",
success:function(xml) {
    alert("sucess");
        jQuery(xml).find('resource').each(
                function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var content = (this).text();
                    alert(name + "-" + content);
                }
            );
        }
});
}
```

now in my html i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n.js"></script>
```

and call to the JS function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setLanguageScript('en');">EN</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setLanguageScript('ro');">RO</a>
```

FireBug gives the message: jQuery().ajax is not a function

Comment: .ajax() is a static method on the jQuery factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.ajax` or just `$.ajax` instead of `jQuery().ajax`

Comment: ok, so i do the change and now the error i get:setLanguageScript is not defined

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg: Either you have an syntax error in your script or `setLanguageScript` is not in global scope. I suggest to put your code on [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/) and see whether it contains any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
jQuery().ajax({
```

to:

```
jQuery.ajax({
```

Reason: `jQuery()` refers to precisely nothing.

Comment: ok, so i do the change and now the error i get:setLanguageScript is not defined